# implementing two commands in one boolean case

Tags: boolean, labview, visa

In the image linked below, I circled the two commands I want to send to my current source.

It's my first time using Labview so I apologize if the question is too basic. I also apologize for not just directly uploading an image here. For some reason, it wouldn't allow me this time.

I can only have one VISA in the code, which is why I have been having a hard time sending two commands in one boolean case.

I was thinking of using a for loop but I am not sure how I should go about doing it.

[image]

Comment: Why do you say *I can only have one VISA in the code*? Is this a requirement someone has told you to meet? It's not a requirement imposed by LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate solution depends on what you want to do.

If the ordering of the commands does not matter, you can simply create a second VISA command block and wire the device to both.

If you need to enforce order, the VISA command block has a device output (directly opposite the device input) so that you can wire the output to another block. This forces the first block/function to complete before the output is available to the second block, thus enforcing execution order. If the second block should only execute if the first block completes successfully, you can wire the error output of the first block to the error input of the second block accomplishing the same effect (thanks for the comment @nekomatic).

If you're using functions that don't have outputs you can use to enforce order of execution, you can wrap them with a sequence structure (flat, stacked, etc). This is cleaner than using a for loop if each "iteration" executes a different command.

You could also use a for loop and an array of commands if you expect execute many commands.

Comment: I like this answer a lot but please don't ever use a stacked sequence structure.

Comment: If a function or VI has error terminals (as all the VISA functions do), you should enforce execution order by wiring `error out` of one to `error in` of the next one. If you don't want to do that because you want the second VI to execute even if the first one gave an error, specifically discard the error by wiring it through a [`Clear Errors`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/glang/clear_errors/) VI.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, solution could be quite simple:
[image]

If needed, after VISA Write.vi function, you could put also some wait function, to have short delay between the commands (but, it depends on the device).